# Lots of Logcat errors after a simple layout change

Tags: android, checkbox, radio-button

My sample application was working just fine until I moved one of my buttons a little bit to the left. Now for whatever reason, I can't seem to fix the errors even though it was running perfectly fine before. There are no errors present in my source code and I am unsure how to resolve this issue.

Here is the source code:

```
package com.example.crazytipcalc;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.SystemClock;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.text.Editable;
import android.text.TextWatcher;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.CheckBox;
import android.widget.Chronometer;
import android.widget.CompoundButton;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.RadioButton;
import android.widget.RadioGroup;
import android.widget.SeekBar;
import android.widget.SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class CrazyTipCalc extends Activity {
    private static final String TOTAL_BILL = "TOTAL_BILL";
    private static final String CURRENT_TIP = "CURRENT_TIP";
    private static final String BILL_WITHOUT_TIP = "BILL_WITHOUT_TIP";
    private double billBeforeTip = 0.0;
    private double tipAmount = 0.0;
    private double finalBill = 0.0;
    EditText billBeforeTipET;
    EditText tipAmountET;
    EditText finalBillET;
    SeekBar tipSeekBar;
    private int[] checklistValues = new int[12];
    CheckBox friendlyCheckBox;
    CheckBox specialsCheckBox;
    CheckBox opinionCheckBox;
    RadioGroup availableRadioGroup;
    RadioButton availableBadRadio;
    RadioButton availableOKRadio;
    RadioButton availableGoodRadio;
    Spinner problemsSpinner;
    Button startChronometerButton;
    Button pauseChronometerButton;
    Button resetChronometerButton;
    Chronometer timeWaitingChronometer;
    long secondsYouWaited = 0;
    TextView timeWaitingTextView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_crazy_tip_calc);

        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            billBeforeTip = 0.0;
            tipAmount = 0.15;
            finalBill = 0.0;
        }
        else {
            billBeforeTip = savedInstanceState.getDouble(BILL_WITHOUT_TIP);
            tipAmount = savedInstanceState.getDouble(CURRENT_TIP);
            finalBill = savedInstanceState.getDouble(TOTAL_BILL);
        }

        billBeforeTipET = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.billEditText);
        tipAmountET = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.tipEditText);
        finalBillET = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.finalBillEditText);      
        tipSeekBar = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.changeTipSeekBar);

        friendlyCheckBox = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.friendlyCheckBox);
        specialsCheckBox = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.specialsCheckBox);
        opinionCheckBox = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.opinionCheckBox);

        setUpIntroCheckBoxes();

        availableRadioGroup = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.availableRadioGroup);
        availableBadRadio = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.availableBadRadio);
        availableOKRadio = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.availableOKRadio);
        availableGoodRadio = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.availableGoodRadio);

        addChangeListenerToRadios();

        problemsSpinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.problemsSpinner);
        addItemSelectedListenerToSpinner();

        startChronometerButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.startChronometerButton);
        pauseChronometerButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.pauseChronometerButton);
        resetChronometerButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.resetChronometerButton);
        timeWaitingChronometer = (Chronometer) findViewById(R.id.timeWaitingChronometer);
        timeWaitingTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.timeWaitingTextView);

        setButtonOnClickListeners();

        billBeforeTipET.addTextChangedListener(billBeforeTipListener);
        tipSeekBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(tipSeekBarListener);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.crazy_tip_calc, menu);
        return true;
    }

    protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);

        outState.putDouble(BILL_WITHOUT_TIP, billBeforeTip);
        outState.putDouble(CURRENT_TIP, tipAmount);
        outState.putDouble(TOTAL_BILL, finalBill);
    }

    private TextWatcher billBeforeTipListener = new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2,
                int arg3) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            try {
                billBeforeTip = Double.parseDouble(s.toString());
            }
            catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                billBeforeTip = 0.0;
            }

            updateTipAndFinalBill();
        }
    };

    private OnSeekBarChangeListener tipSeekBarListener = new OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar arg0, int arg1, boolean arg2) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            tipAmount = (tipSeekBar.getProgress()) * .01;
            tipAmountET.setText(String.format("%.02f", tipAmount));
            updateTipAndFinalBill();
        }

        @Override
        public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    };

    private void updateTipAndFinalBill() {
        tipAmount = Double.parseDouble(tipAmountET.getText().toString());

        finalBill = billBeforeTip + (billBeforeTip * tipAmount);
        finalBillET.setText(String.format("%.02f", finalBill));
    }

    private void setUpIntroCheckBoxes() {
        friendlyCheckBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CheckBox.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton arg0, boolean arg1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                checklistValues[0] = (friendlyCheckBox.isChecked())?4:0;
                setTipFromWaitressChecklist();

                updateTipAndFinalBill();
            }
        });

        specialsCheckBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CheckBox.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton arg0, boolean arg1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                checklistValues[1] = (specialsCheckBox.isChecked())?1:0;
                setTipFromWaitressChecklist();

                updateTipAndFinalBill();
            }
        });

        opinionCheckBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CheckBox.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton arg0, boolean arg1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                checklistValues[2] = (opinionCheckBox.isChecked())?2:0;
                setTipFromWaitressChecklist();

                updateTipAndFinalBill();
            }
        });
    }

    private void setTipFromWaitressChecklist() {
        int checklistTotal = 0;

        for (int item : checklistValues) {
            checklistTotal += item;
        }

        tipAmountET.setText(String.format("%.02f", checklistTotal * .01));
    }

    private void addChangeListenerToRadios() {
        availableRadioGroup.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener(){
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                checklistValues[3] = (availableBadRadio.isSelected())?-1:0;
                checklistValues[4] = (availableOKRadio.isSelected())?2:0;
                checklistValues[5] = (availableGoodRadio.isSelected())?4:0;

                setTipFromWaitressChecklist();

                updateTipAndFinalBill();
            }
        });
    }

    private void addItemSelectedListenerToSpinner() {
        problemsSpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new Spinner.OnItemSelectedListener(){
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                    int arg2, long arg3) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                checklistValues[6] = (problemsSpinner.getSelectedItem()).equals("Bad")?-1:0;
                checklistValues[7] = (problemsSpinner.getSelectedItem()).equals("OK")?3:0;
                checklistValues[8] = (problemsSpinner.getSelectedItem()).equals("Good")?6:0;

                setTipFromWaitressChecklist();

                updateTipAndFinalBill();
            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }
        });
    }

    private void setButtonOnClickListeners() {
        startChronometerButton.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                int stoppedMilliseconds = 0;

                String chronoText = timeWaitingChronometer.getText().toString();
                String array[] = chronoText.split(":");

                if (array.length == 2) {
                    stoppedMilliseconds = Integer.parseInt(array[0]) * 60 * 1000 + Integer.parseInt(array[1]) * 1000;
                }
                else if (array.length == 3){
                    stoppedMilliseconds = Integer.parseInt(array[0]) * 60 * 60 * 1000 + Integer.parseInt(array[1]) * 60 * 1000 + Integer.parseInt(array[2]) * 1000;
                }

                timeWaitingChronometer.setBase(SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() - stoppedMilliseconds);

                secondsYouWaited = Long.parseLong(array[1]);

                updateTipBasedOnTimeWaited(secondsYouWaited);

                timeWaitingChronometer.start();
            }
        });

        pauseChronometerButton.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                timeWaitingChronometer.stop();
            }
        });

        resetChronometerButton.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                timeWaitingChronometer.setBase(SystemClock.elapsedRealtime());

                secondsYouWaited = 0;
            }
        });
    }

    private void updateTipBasedOnTimeWaited(long secondsYouWaited) {
        checklistValues[9] = (secondsYouWaited > 10)?-2:2;
//      checklistValues[10] = (secondsYouWaited > 10)?-2:0;
//      checklistValues[11] = (secondsYouWaited > 10)?-2:0;

        setTipFromWaitressChecklist();

        updateTipAndFinalBill();
    }
}
```

And here is the logcat:

```
02-03 01:55:17.044: E/AndroidRuntime(10237): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-03 01:55:17.044: E/AndroidRuntime(10237): Process: com.example.crazytipcalc, PID: 10237
02-03 01:55:17.044: E/AndroidRuntime(10237): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.crazytipcalc/com.example.crazytipcalc.CrazyTipCalc}: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.RadioButton cannot be cast to android.widget.CheckBox
02-03 01:55:17.044: E/AndroidRuntime(10237):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2215)
02-03 01:55:17.044: E/AndroidRuntime(10237):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2265)
02-03 01:55:17.044: E/AndroidRuntime(10237):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:145)
02-03 01:55:17.044: E/AndroidRuntime(10237):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1206)
02-03 01:55:17.044: E/AndroidRuntime(10237):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
02-03 01:55:17.044: E/AndroidRuntime(10237):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
02-03 01:55:17.044: E/AndroidRuntime(10237):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5081)
02-03 01:55:17.044: E/AndroidRuntime(10237):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-03 01:55:17.044: E/AndroidRuntime(10237):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
02-03 01:55:17.044: E/AndroidRuntime(10237):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:781)
02-03 01:55:17.044: E/AndroidRuntime(10237):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
02-03 01:55:17.044: E/AndroidRuntime(10237):    at de.robv.android.xposed.XposedBridge.main(XposedBridge.java:126)
02-03 01:55:17.044: E/AndroidRuntime(10237):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
02-03 01:55:17.044: E/AndroidRuntime(10237): Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.RadioButton cannot be cast to android.widget.CheckBox
02-03 01:55:17.044: E/AndroidRuntime(10237):    at com.example.crazytipcalc.CrazyTipCalc.onCreate(CrazyTipCalc.java:72)
02-03 01:55:17.044: E/AndroidRuntime(10237):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
02-03 01:55:17.044: E/AndroidRuntime(10237):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
02-03 01:55:17.044: E/AndroidRuntime(10237):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2169)
02-03 01:55:17.044: E/AndroidRuntime(10237):    ... 12 more
```

I can provide the AndroidManifest.xml as well if that will help with troubleshooting. I am fairly new to Android development, so it just seems strange to me that an app would work perfectly fine and then break after shifting a button.

activity_crazy_calc_tip.xml:

> ```
> <TextView
>     android:id="@+id/billTextView"
>     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
>     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>     android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
>     android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
>     android:layout_marginLeft="28dp"
>     android:layout_marginTop="22dp"
>     android:text="@string/bill_text_view" />
>
> <EditText
>     android:id="@+id/billEditText"
>     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
>     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>     android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/billTextView"
>     android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/billTextView"
>     android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/billTextView"
>     android:ems="5"
>     android:inputType="numberDecimal"
>     android:text="@string/bill_edit_text" />
>
> <TextView
>     android:id="@+id/tipTextView"
>     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
>     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>     android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/billEditText"
>     android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/billEditText"
>     android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
>     android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/billEditText"
>     android:text="@string/tip_text_view" />
>
> <EditText
>     android:id="@+id/tipEditText"
>     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
>     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>     android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/tipTextView"
>     android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/tipTextView"
>     android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/tipTextView"
>     android:ems="4"
>     android:inputType="numberDecimal"
>     android:text="@string/tip_edit_text" >
> </EditText>
>
> <TextView
>     android:id="@+id/finalBillTextView"
>     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
>     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>     android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/tipEditText"
>     android:layout_below="@+id/tipEditText"
>     android:layout_marginTop="19dp"
>     android:text="@string/final_bill_text_view" />
>
> <EditText
>     android:id="@+id/finalBillEditText"
>     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
>     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>     android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/tipTextView"
>     android:layout_below="@+id/finalBillTextView"
>     android:ems="5"
>     android:inputType="numberDecimal" />
>
> <TextView
>     android:id="@+id/changeTipTextView"
>     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
>     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>     android:layout_above="@+id/finalBillEditText"
>     android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/billTextView"
>     android:text="@string/change_tip_text_view" />
>
> <SeekBar
>     android:id="@+id/changeTipSeekBar"
>     android:layout_width="match_parent"
>     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>     android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/finalBillEditText"
>     android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
>     android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/tipTextView"
>     android:progress="15" />
>
> <TextView
>     android:id="@+id/introTextView"
>     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
>     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>     android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/changeTipTextView"
>     android:layout_below="@+id/changeTipSeekBar"
>     android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
>     android:text="@string/intro_text_view" />
>
> <TextView
>     android:id="@+id/availableTextView"
>     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
>     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>     android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/introTextView"
>     android:layout_below="@+id/friendlyCheckBox"
>     android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
>     android:text="@string/available_text_view" />
>
> <Button
>     android:id="@+id/pauseChronometerButton"
>     style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
>     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
>     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>     android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/startChronometerButton"
>     android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/startChronometerButton"
>     android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
>     android:text="@string/pause_chronometer_button" />
>
> <Button
>     android:id="@+id/startChronometerButton"
>     style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
>     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
>     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>     android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/problemsSpinner"
>     android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
>     android:layout_marginBottom="30dp"
>     android:text="@string/start_chronometer_button" />
>
> <CheckBox
>     android:id="@+id/friendlyCheckBox"
>     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
>     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>     android:layout_alignRight="@+id/availableTextView"
>     android:layout_below="@+id/introTextView"
>     android:text="@string/intro_friendly_checkbox" />
>
> <CheckBox
>     android:id="@+id/specialsCheckBox"
>     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
>     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>     android:layout_above="@+id/availableTextView"
>     android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/introTextView"
>     android:text="@string/intro_specials_checkbox" />
>
> <CheckBox
>     android:id="@+id/opinionCheckBox"
>     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
>     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>     android:layout_above="@+id/availableTextView"
>     android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/specialsCheckBox"
>     android:text="@string/intro_opinion_checkbox" />
>
> <RadioGroup
>     android:id="@+id/availableRadioGroup"
>     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
>     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>     android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/availableTextView"
>     android:layout_below="@+id/availableTextView"
>     android:orientation="horizontal" >
>
>     <RadioButton
>         android:id="@+id/availableBadRadio"
>         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
>         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>         android:checked="true"
>         android:text="@string/available_bad_radiobutton" />
>
>     <RadioButton
>         android:id="@+id/availableOKRadio"
>         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
>         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>         android:text="@string/available_ok_radiobutton" />
>
>     <RadioButton
>         android:id="@+id/availableGoodRadio"
>         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
>         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>         android:text="@string/available_good_radiobutton" />
> </RadioGroup>
>
> <Spinner
>     android:id="@+id/problemsSpinner"
>     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
>     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>     android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/availableRadioGroup"
>     android:layout_below="@+id/availableRadioGroup"
>     android:layout_marginTop="14dp"
>     android:entries="@array/problem_solving" />
>
> <TextView
>     android:id="@+id/timeWaitingTextView"
>     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
>     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>     android:layout_below="@+id/problemsSpinner"
>     android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
>     android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/finalBillEditText"
>     android:text="@string/time_waiting_text_view" />
>
> <Chronometer
>     android:id="@+id/timeWaitingChronometer"
>     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
>     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>     android:layout_alignTop="@+id/timeWaitingTextView"
>     android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/availableRadioGroup" />
>
> <Button
>     android:id="@+id/resetChronometerButton"
>     style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
>     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
>     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>     android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/pauseChronometerButton"
>     android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/pauseChronometerButton"
>     android:layout_alignRight="@+id/finalBillEditText"
>     android:text="@string/reset_chronometer_button" />
> ```

Comment: show your activity_crazy_tip_calc.xml

Comment: why bother, just read the error.

Comment: Have you try to clean you project ?

Comment: Please post your layout file code.

Comment: Thanks @GrIsHu, cleaning the project worked. I changed nothing in my code or my XML file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just try to clean your project once and then run again. There is no issue with your code. 
As you have tried to change your `Button` a bit so may be your R.java file have referenced some wrong view's ids.

Answer (score 1):

In line 72 of **CrazyTipCalc.java** you have a line which looks like

`(Checkbox) findViewById (R.id.something)` in your `onCreate` method where **something** is a `RadioButton` and not a Checkbox.

Comment: I looked at the corresponding error and it doesn't make sense:
`CheckBox specialsCheckBox;
specialsCheckBox = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.specialsCheckBox);`

Comment: Your code is correct but in your XML layout but I'm guessing that  your `specialsCheckBox` is a RadioButton. Post your XML so someone can take a look.

Comment: `specialsCheckBox` is a CheckBox in my XML code. The problem was solved by cleaning the project. Thanks for your help anyway.

Answer (score 1):

As often the case, the clue **is** in the logcat. See this line:

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.RadioButton cannot be cast to android.widget.CheckBox
```

It says that you are trying to cast RadioButton to CheckBox. See the line below it:

```
at com.example.crazytipcalc.CrazyTipCalc.onCreate(CrazyTipCalc.java:72)
```

It points to the line that's causing the problem (one of these 3):

```
friendlyCheckBox = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.friendlyCheckBox);
specialsCheckBox = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.specialsCheckBox);
opinionCheckBox = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.opinionCheckBox);
```

`friendlyCheckBox`, `specialsCheckbox`, and `opinionCheckBox` are of type CheckBox, so check your **xml layout** and make sure that the components with ids `friendlyCheckBox`, `specialsCheckBox` and `opinionCheckBox` are also CheckBoxes, as most likely one of them is of RadioButton type :)

Comment: Thanks. I should have mentioned that I have tried to troubleshoot by following along with the logcat, but that it didn't make sense to me because my code is correct. My XML file was correct as well. It was working fine and then moving a button caused the whole app to crash.

I was able to solve the issue by cleaning my project. I did not make any changes to my source code or to the XML file. Thanks for your help though!

Answer (score 0):

this means:
     Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.RadioButton cannot be cast to   android.widget.CheckBox

you accidently used findViewById method for cast radiobutton to checkBox.